# React native. How to pass state from component to BottomTab.Screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got navigation made with **bottom-tab navigation** in react native.

**Example code**

```
<BottomTab.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={RootPasswordsHandler}
    options={(): {
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }: { color: any }) => JSX.Element;
      headerRight: () => JSX.Element;
      title: string;
    } => ({
      title: globalState.languageHandler.screenNames.HOME_SCREEN,
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }): JSX.Element => 
          <TabBarIcon name="home" color={color} />,
      headerRight: (): JSX.Element => (
        <TextInput style={styles.navStyles.input} 
          placeholder={globalState.languageHandler.generic.FIND_PASSWORD} />
      ),
    })}
  />
```

In component **RootPasswordsHandler**, component fetch passwords from database, save them in local state `useState` and render them.

I would like to add input `as in code example above`, which will access that data and filter array of passwords.

How can I achieve that ? I am pretty new to react native and I am completely stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setOptions` in your component and then access them in `BottomTab`

Example from [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#setoptions) see how `value` is passed!

```js
function ProfileScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState(route.params.title);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: value === '' ? 'No title' : value,
    });
  }, [navigation, value]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={value}
      />
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: That was fast :O . Much tanks. Thats what I wanted <3